# How to test aws S3 in mocha

Tags: amazon-s3, mocha.js, chai, sinon, aws-sdk-mock

This is my first Mocha/Chai attempt at testing. What would be the best way to do integration testing in mocha with aws S3. I try to mock aws S3 using aws-sdk-mock and sinon but I really don't know how and where to mock this?

Here is my code:

```
// documentController

var aws = require('aws-sdk');
aws.config.update({
    accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    region: 'ap-southeast-1'
});
var s3 = new aws.S3({apiVersion: '2006-03-01'});

function deleteObject(key) {
    s3.deleteObject({
        'Bucket': 'delete-bucket',
        'Key': key,
    }, function(err, data) {
        return
    })
};

create: function(req, res) {
   sails.async.auto(req, {
        getDocumentContent: ['teamPrefDoc', 'getDocument', function (results, cb) {
                var docKey = (
                    results.getDocument && results.getDocument.key
                ) ? results.getDocument.key : '';
                var bucket = 'individual-docs';
                if (!docKey || !bucket) {
                    return res.badRequest("Document doesn't have a key");
                }
                var params = {
                    Bucket: bucket,
                    Key: docKey
                };
                var tempDocStream = fs.createWriteStream(tempFileName + '.doc');
                var s3Stream = s3.getObject(params).createReadStream();
                s3Stream.pipe(tempDocStream).on('close', function() {
                    tempDocStream.close();
                    return cb(null, true);
                }).on('error', function(err) {
                    sails.log(err);
                    return cb(null, false);
                });
            }],
       'savePdfToS3': ['convertToPdfLocally', function (results, cb) {
                if (!results.convertToPdfLocally) {
                    return cb(null, false)
                }
                var s3Key = results.documentDoc.key + '/pdf';
                fs.readFile(tempFileName + '.pdf', (err, pdfBuffer) => {
                    if (err) { return cb(err); }
                    s3.putObject({
                        'Bucket': results.getDocumentContent,
                        'Key': s3Key,
                        'Body': pdfBuffer,
                        'ContentType': 'application/pdf'
                    }, function(err, data) {
                        if (err) { return cb(err); }
                        Documents.update({
                            id: id
                        }, {
                            pdf_key: s3Key
                        }).exec(function(err, updatedDocs) {
                            if (err) {
                                sails.log("Couldn't write pdf url to document", err);
                                return cb(err);
                            }
                            return cb(null, updatedDocs[0]);
                        });
                    })
                });
            }],
   }
}
```

I have an API that runs create function which runs some database queries and saves the doc to s3. So, I want to test this API but I don't know how to mock s3.getObject and s3.putObject.

Here is my test file that run setup and teardown connection

```
// bootstrap.test.js

var sinon = require('sinon')
var AWSMock = require('aws-sdk-mock')

before(async () => {
     const getObjectStub = AWS.S3.prototype.getObject = sinon.stub();
     var s3 = new Aws.S3();
     AWSMock.mock('S3', 'getObject', function(parmas,callback){
         console.log("Callback received for getObject");
         callback(null,'Success');
     });
     AWSMock.mock('S3', 'deleteObject', function(param,callback){
       callback(null,{'s3deleteMarker': true 
         ,'s3DeleteVersionId': 'VERSION ID' 
         ,'s3DeletedImageSourceUid': 'SOURCE' 
         ,'s3DeletedKey': 'KEY'});
     });
```

Here is my test code:

```
// document.test.js

describe('document controller', () => {
        it('should upload a doc', done => {
            defaultDocument.resourceId = caseIds[0],
            request(sails.hooks.http.app)
            .post(`${apiVersion}/new/documents?app=test`)
            .set('Authorization', `Bearer ${process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN}`)
            .field(defaultDocument)
            .attach('document0', 'some_pdf.pdf')
            .expect(200)
            .end((err, res)=> {
                if(err) {
                    return done(err)
                }
                console.log(res.body)
                done()
            })
        })
    })
```

I am fairly new to unit tests, so I am happy for any direction you can point me in :-)

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The key point about the aws-sdk-mock is that "The AWS Service needs to be initialised inside the function being tested in order for the SDK method to be mocked".

It's hard to know how this is going to work using the dictionary controller style you are using (there maybe too much magic going on for the mocking to work:

```
module.exports = {
  login: function (req, res) { ... },
  logout: function (req, res) { ... },
  signup: function (req, res) { ... },
}
```

sails is super opinionated in how your code is structured and I don't think you'll be able to create integration tests that exercise your api directly, no matter how you structure your controllers, without a whole lot of hacking.

The sails documentation recommends moving code that that isn't dependent on the request, response into helper functions like your **deleteObject** function. Pull out similar functions for the contents of getDocumentContent  and place them in a separate module. Then you would still need to instantiate the object in each helper function:

```
const s3 = new aws.S3();
```

What I would do would be to rewrite my helper functions like

```
function deleteObject(s3, key) {
     s3.deleteObject...
}
```

This way you can pass in anything you like and make assertions that prove that the request to the s3 object are built up as expected under different scenarios.

I'd write my integration tests to take the happy path and write to an actual s3 bucket.